# Where can I store army cars

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I have a stolen army car but won't let me store it in my garage, i have taken it to los santos customs and got it fixed and says i can get insurance but Is there any where I can store it or not ?

Comment: When you insure a car it automatically gets moved to a free garage spot, does it not?

Comment: ^^ This.  When you insure a car it will ask if you want to replace one, if your garage is full, so it definitely needs a spot in there.  Can you get insurance on a tank??? :p

Comment: @Archer Once you buy a tank you can call it in via Pegasus anytime, even after it got destroyed. It'll cost some money, which can be seen as the insurance money if you will. Otherwise you can't insure a tank.